# Does The Stored Procedure sp_removedbreplication Remove Rowguids

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

In merge replication if I run sp_removedbreplication will that remove rowguids or not?

Will it take into account the preserve_rowguidcol values in the sysmergearticles table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.sysmergearticles SET preserve_rowguidcol = 1 WHERE type = 10 and name = 'MyTable'
```

It will preserve the rowguid column for the article.